# Set textarea height to occupy rest of the screen

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am new to react-native. Building a Hello World app to make myself well versed with react-native. On a screen, I want to have a textbox, below it a button and below the button a textarea that will occupy the rest of the screen. I am not sure how shall I do it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand about Flex Box to set layout as per your need.

**Layout with flexbox**

> A component can specify the layout of its children using the flexbox
>   algorithm. Flexbox is designed to provide a consistent layout on
>   different screen sizes.
>
> You will normally use a combination of `flexDirection`, `alignItems`,
>   and `justifyContent` to achieve the right layout.
>
> **Flex Direction**
>
> Adding flexDirection to a component's style determines the primary
>   axis of its layout. Should the children be organized horizontally
>   (row) or vertically (column)? The default is column.
>
> **Justify Content**
>
> Adding justifyContent to a component's style determines the
>   distribution of children along the primary axis. Should children be
>   distributed at the start, the center, the end, or spaced evenly?
>   Available options are flex-start, center, flex-end, space-around,
>   space-between and space-evenly.
>
> **Align Items**
>
> Adding alignItems to a component's style determines the alignment of
>   children along the secondary axis (if the primary axis is row, then
>   the secondary is column, and vice versa). Should children be aligned
>   at the start, the center, the end, or stretched to fill? Available
>   options are flex-start, center, flex-end, and stretch.

Please check this link to understand flexbox:

1. [Understading flexbox in react native](https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/understanding-flex-in-react-native-b34dfb4b16d1)
2. [Layout with flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox)